# Inserting item in list in python

Tags: python, django, list

I have this query below:

```
high_results = list(
    high_structures.values_list('bldg_name', 'bldg_type').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
high_results.insert(0, 3)

medium_results = list(
    medium_structures.values_list('bldg_name', 'bldg_type').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
medium_results.insert(0, 2)

low_results = list(low_structures.values_list('bldg_name', 'bldg_type').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name')))
low_results.insert(0, 1)
```

in which i want to insert an item in the list but the problem, the result is not right.

```
[3, ["Unknown", "Residential", 128], 2, ["Unknown", "Residential", 243], 1, ["Rural Health Center", "Other Government Offices", 1], ["Unknown", "Residential", 384], ["Katugasan Multi-Purpose Gym", "Sport Center/Gymnasium/Covered Court", 1], ["Katugasan Elementary School", "School", 5]]
```

It is not enclosed in a bracket, or it is separated. How do I solve it?
The output should be like this:

```
[ [3,"Unknown", "Residential", 128],  [2,"Unknown", "Residential", 243], [ 1,"Rural Health Center", "Other Government Offices", 1],...]
```

OUTPUT:

```
# Combine all of the structures into a unified response
results = list(chain(high_results, medium_results, low_results))
```

Comment: Presumably you are using `high_results + medium_results + low_results` as the final output then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want to prepend this result to *each result set* from a query. This is best done with a list comprehension then:

```
high_results = [(3,) + row for row in high_structures.values_list('bldg_name', 'bldg_type').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name'))]
medium_results =  [(2,) + row for row in medium_structures.values_list('bldg_name', 'bldg_type').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name'))]
low_results = [(1,) + row for row in low_structures.values_list('bldg_name', 'bldg_type').annotate(count=Count('bldg_name'))]
```

The `(3,) +` prefix is easier to follow than your `high_results.insert(0, 3)` call, which would also require you to convert each nested tuple and then apply the `list.insert()` call in a loop.

You could just concatenate these lists together rather than use `chain()` here:

```
output = high_results + medium_results + low_results
```

Comment: I got this error: `can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`

Comment: @SachiTekina: so the result set is a tuple; did you want tuples or lists as output?

Comment: @SachiTekina: I've adjusted the code to just stick with tuples.

Comment: Iists within the list is the output.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how the output you show is produced? How is it related to the 3 `_results` variables, for example?

Comment: @SachiTekina: note that your `low_results` is a whole sequence of rows, not just one. Where did you envision the `1` being inserted there?

Comment: In every lists from low_results, it should insert 1, for medium_results insert 2, and for high _results insert 3.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have `high_results` as a list in a list. Compare

```
>>> high_results = [["Unknown", "Residential", 128]]
>>> high_results.insert(0, 3)
>>> high_results
[3, ['Unknown', 'Residential', 128]]
```

with

```
>>> high_results = [["Unknown", "Residential", 128]]
>>> high_results[0].insert(0, 3)
>>> high_results
[[3, 'Unknown', 'Residential', 128]]
```

In the case that high_results has more than one element, and you wish to prepend `3` to each one

```
high_results = [[3] + x for x in high_results]
```

similarly for the others